# Understanding a definition of the exterior derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields

I'm trying to prove the exact same formula as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680909/prove-coordinate-free-formula-for-the-exterior-derivative-using-cartans-magic-f):

$U \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ an open set, $\omega$ a k-differential form on $U$, $X_0, \dots, X_k$ vector fields on U, i. e. elements of $C^{\infty}(U)^n$.

I am supposed to show (for k = 1, 2):

$$d\omega(X_0, ... , X_k) = \sum_i (-1)^i X_i(\omega(X_0, ... , \hat{X_i}, ... , X_k)) + \sum_{i < j}(-1)^{i+j}\omega([X_i, X_j], X_0, ... , \hat{X_i}, ... , \hat{X_j}, ..., X_k)$$

In the lecture I'm following we did not learn about Cartans magic formula. I don't even know what $(\mathcal{L}_Y \omega)$ means.

My main problem is: I'm struggling to understand what $X_i(\omega(X_0, ... , \hat{X_i}, ... , X_k))$ is: I thought $\omega(X_0, ... , \hat{X_i}, ... , X_k)$ is an element of $C^{\infty}(U)$. How can we feed it to $X_i$?

Comment: You are right, $\omega(X_0,\ldots,\hat X_i,\ldots,X_k)$ is an element of $C^\infty(U)$. A vector field $X_i$ is a linear map $X_i:C^\infty(U)\rightarrow C^\infty(U)$ (and a derivation), so it can be fed a smooth function. (See [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#Vector_fields_on_manifolds) on Wikipedia) Your confusion probably arises from the fact that there are several equivalent ways of defining vector fields.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was missing!